# Mobile media queries issue

Tags: css, iphone

I have a html5 theme that came with a responsive css .
I want to add a media query for Iphone 6 plus.
  I have a query that works well on iphone 5, like this

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
 #header .top .inner,
 section.news-ticker,
 .section3 .section-wrap,
 .section2 .section-wrap,
 #main,
 .section-navMobile,
 .footer-wrapper { width: 300px;}
```

This media query on Iphone 6 plus gives too much margin right and left, so I wanted to add a new media query with a max width of 736 px and give the #main section a width of 360px
But it doesn’t work.. on iphone 6 plus I still have the large right and left margins , ignores the 360px of the main container
I tried different combinations of media widths and no luck

something I must be doing wrong ...

Comment: could you give the code that you used for the iphone 6 as well?

Comment: yes, I tried:@media (max-width: 736px) {
 #header .top .inner,
 section.news-ticker,
 .section3 .section-wrap,
 .section2 .section-wrap,
 #main,
 .section-navMobile,
 .footer-wrapper { width: 360px;}

Comment: Working with specific widths like this can always be tricky.  Are you stuck on using a specific width like 360px?  Why don't you use a percentage like 90%?  That way it will stay consistent amongst multiple devices at multiple resolutions.

Comment: yes, thank you ! it worked with 90%  but since I’ll have to change other widths on the style I would also like to use a media query that only affects Iphone 6 plus... I wonder why using  @media (max-width: 736px) doesn’t change anything on the iphone 6 plus

Comment: The only way to really be able to tell is to see more of your code.  There could be issues with the html or css, but its hard to tell with the little snippet that you gave. My only other suggestion before you do that is to add `@media only screen (max-width: 736px)`

Comment: @media only screen (max-width: 736px)  doesn’t do anything either

Comment: That is an error; the correct syntax is `@media only screen and (max-width: 736px)` with an `and`.

Comment: @Mr Lister. yep you are right.  I don't know how I messed that up

Comment: if I use `@media only screen and (max-width: 736px)`  for some reason  over rides the Iphone 5  `@media only screen and (max-width: 479px)` and it doesn’t look all right either

Comment: Hmm, that may be because of the placement of the media query.